# JavaScript: Creating an every function for an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to create an "every" function for an array. I am aware that it is already built-in, but I just want to enhance my programming skills.

```js
let every = (arr, f) => {
    for (let element of arr) {
        if (f(element)) {
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
        } 
    }
} 

console.log(every([2, 4, 6], n => {n % 2 === 0})) // <-- false
```

Why is it giving me false. Could someone please spot the error? Thank you!

Comment: Two things: 1: You’re only testing the first entry. Your `return` statement exits the loop and the function, and 2) your evenness test function doesn’t return anything at all so it always evaluates to false in a boolean context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you function not return.

try this:

```js
console.log(every([2, 4, 6], n => {return n % 2 === 0}))
```

Answer (score 3):

Two mistakes:

1. Either change the test function to `n => {return n % 2 === 0}` or `n => n % 2 === 0`
2. Your for loop should return false immediately if any element fails the test. Then, if nothing fails, you return true after the loop.

```js
let every = (arr, f) => {
  for (let element of arr) {
    if(!f(element)) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
} 

console.log(every([2, 4, 6], n => n % 2 === 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a revised version of your implementation that fixes two issues:

1. Your evenness arrow function wasn't returning anything, so it always evaluated to false in a boolean context.

```js
// doesn't return anything
n => {n % 2 === 0}

// fixed with explicit return
n => {return n % 2 === 0}

// fixed with implicit return by removing the {}
n => n % 2 === 0
```

2. Returning the result of the first evaluation:

```js
if (f(element)) {
  return true // <== this exits the function the first time it's encountered
}
else {
  return false // <== so does this
}
```

Fixed by returning false if an entry doesn't pass the test function, and returning true only after all elements have been evaluated.

```js
let every = (arr, f) => {
    for (let element of arr) {
        if (!f(element)) {
            return false // only need one negative to know we should return false
        }
    }
    return true;
} 

console.log(every([2, 4, 6], n => n % 2 === 0)) // true
console.log(every([2, 5, 6], n => n % 2 === 0)) // false
```